# Динамическое отображение данных в UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios7

Посоветуйте ресурсы с примером динамической загрузки данных в UICollectionView, например, надо загрузить из интернета 100 картинок, грузим 10 раз по 10 и добавляем их в CollectionView по мере загрузки. 
Пока встречал только примеры типа "вот 4 картинки, сейчас мы их отобразим в CollectionView"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда мы сталкивались с подобным, то грузили картнки в методе cellForRowAtindexPath (мы работали с таблицей, но насколько понимаю это не принципиально) на лету с помощью блоков асинхронно (сейчас можно запустить `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...` , но тогда у нас была поддержка iOS4), только стоит ввести какой-нибудь флажок или отмену соединения на случай что картинка уже нужна (т.е. что ячейка не перегрузилась и должна показывать уже другую сущность). Код привести не могу т.к. по факту у нас все было несколько сложнее - мы использовали еще и кеширование в локальной папке между вызовами/на случай офлайн-просмотра, выдрать оттуда именно эту часть весьма сложно

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение - [документация по коллекциям от Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/UICollectionView_class.pdf)

1. Создать `DataSource` унаследованный от `UICollectionViewDataSource`
2. При изменении `DataSource` (это NSMutableArray) вызывать метод `reloadData` у `CollectionView`

Comment: 1. Протоколы это не наследование, это просто декларация что те или иные методы будут в классе, который поддерживает протокол

2. Тут есть ряд минусов: зачем перерисовывать все ячейки каждый раз при загрузке одной картинки (вы же их не зипом все вместе выкачиваете?), ячейки могли уже и пропасть с экрана (пролистнуться) и перерисовка вообще не к чему

Comment: для большого списка это минус, тогда надо будет динамически с другого конца массив укорачивать, чтобы память не занимать. Но это тоже не хорошо. У меня данные из базы берутся и проблему решил кешированием